# Java illegal Start of an Expression error

Tags: java

```
class FishingHour
{
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
         public void fishing(){
             int totalHoursFishing = 0;
             int hoursAllowedFishing = 4;
             for(int i=1;i<25;++i)
             {
                 totalHoursFishing = ++totalHoursFishing;
                 if(hoursAllowedFishing>totalHoursFishing)
                     break;
                 System.out.println("Fishing for hours"+i+".");
             }
         }
    }
}
```

hey guys....i'm just a starter in java language.....
my problem is, that this program is not compiling......& giving me "Illegal start of an Expression" error.......can any'one help me....??/

Comment: `fishing()` is inside `main()`. Thanks god your computer didn't explode.

Comment: Just put the fishing() method under the main method but within the class.

Answer (score 3):

You have your method `fishing()` inside the `main()` method. Methods don't nest that way.

Answer (score 2):

you can not write one method inside another another method.Java does not support nested methods.Move your fishing() outside the main method.

basic structure

```
class x
{
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
         //codes
     }
     public void method()
     {
        //codes
     }
}
```

Comment: @MarounMaroun may be your comment have attracted the downvote,just tell me If my answer is wrong or not?

Comment: I think this post originally had the method outside the class and someone down-voted when that was the case.

Comment: My comment doesn't say your answer is wrong.. I was just mentioning that you can have anonymous class inside some method, and this class can have method inside it.. So.. somehow, you can have method inside anonymous class inside method..

Comment: @leigero downvoters may be thinking that I even dont know how to write basic methods.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method inside a method.

you can't do this

`fishing()` is inside `main()`. you can't have nested method.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have a method inside another one in Java. So you must put fishing() method outside main() method. For example put it above the main() method in your class.

Answer (score 0):

Methods cannot be nested! main() is a special type of method from which the program starts. Separate fishing() method.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the correct way to declare a method inside another instead go for method calling and declared outside the `main()` but inside your class "`FishingHour`"...

Comment: Nice gravatar. Baahubali :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class NewClassa {
     public void fishing(){
             int totalHoursFishing = 0;
             int hoursAllowedFishing = 4;
             for(int i=1;i<25;++i)
             {

                 totalHoursFishing = ++totalHoursFishing;
                 if(hoursAllowedFishing>totalHoursFishing)
                     break;
                 System.out.println("Fishing for hours"+i+".");
             }

     }
  public static void main(String args[])
     {


         NewClassa classa=new NewClassa();
         classa.fishing();
         }


}
```

main is a function and you have written a new function inside main function that was the error.
any way the code is note correct because the if condition is satisfied in the first loop itself and it control goes out of the loop.
break  means stop looping
use continue then it will skip the current iteration and move to the next iteration